# Need help understanding a query involving "case" and "select into" clauses

Tags: sql, t-sql, sql-server-2008r2-express

I am puzzled by the output of the following query:

```
select 
  'Eq Type' =
  case
    when 
      substring([Eq Type], 1, charindex('-', [Eq Type]) - 1) = 
      substring([Eq Type], charindex('-', [Eq Type]) + 1, len([Eq Type])) 
    then
      substring([Eq Type], 1, charindex('-', [Eq Type]) - 1)
    when
      substring([Eq Type], 1, charindex('-', [Eq Type]) - 1) <> 
      substring([Eq Type], charindex('-', [Eq Type]) + 1, len([Eq Type]))
    then
      replace([Eq Type], '-', '')
    else
      null
  end,
  'Failure_Class' =
  case
    when charindex('-', [Eq Type]) <> 0 and
      (substring([Eq Type], 1, charindex('-', [Eq Type]) - 1) = 
      substring([Eq Type], charindex('-', [Eq Type]) + 1, len([Eq Type])))
    then
      substring([Eq Type], 1, charindex('-', [Eq Type]) - 1)
    when charindex('-', [Eq Type]) <> 0 and
      (substring([Eq Type], 1, charindex('-', [Eq Type]) - 1) <>
      substring([Eq Type], charindex('-', [Eq Type]) + 1, len([Eq Type])))
    then
      substring([Eq Type], 1, charindex('-', [Eq Type]) - 1) +
      '\' +
      replace([Eq Type], '-', '')
    when CHARINDEX('-', [Eq Type]) = 0
    then 
      Failure_Class
    else
      null
  end
from dbo.Location
```

1. The Location table contains 25385 records but only 8157 records are returned. Why are records filtered out?
2. When I try to add into dbo.ModifiedLocation to the above query, it fails with the following error: "Invalid length parameter passed to the LEFT or SUBSTRING function". The message is pretty descriptive but why this error is raised when I add the into clause? Why is the query executed normally without the into clause?

**Edit**
I would like to explain what I am trying to achieve. The original dataset has two columns I am interested in, Eq Type and Failure_Class. The data looks as follows:

```
Eq Type, Failure_Class
ACCU-ACCU, ACCU
AUX-AUX, AUX
VA-BA, VA
VA-CH, VA
IP-LS, IP
null, null
VE, VE
JB, JB
VA, null
```

Because the data is maintained by hand, it's inconsistent. I need the data in the following format, in order to be able to import it into their asset management system.

```
Eq Type, Failure_Class
ACCU, ACCU
AUX, AUX
VABA, VA\VABA
VACH, VA\VACH
IPLS, IP\IPLS
null, null
VE, VE
JB, JB
VA, VA
```

**Edit 2**
It seems that I have found the problem. I was running this query in the freeware version of Toad 5.6 for SQL Server. When I have switched to SSMS and removed the "into dbo.ModifiedLocation" the query raised the familiar "Invalid length parameter passed to the LEFT or SUBSTRING function" error. This answers my second question. I am guessing that if I resolve this error, I'll get the desired output. Thank you for your help.

Comment: Can you post the data or a sample of the data from dbo.Location and the result you get when running the statement to allow someone to help

Comment: @Trevor Done. Hopefully, it clarifies what I am trying to accomplish.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To insert into an existing table, you need `INSERT INTO dbo.ModifiedLocation SELECT ...`

The `SELECT ... INTO dbo.ModifiedLocation FROM ...` syntax is for creating the table as well as inserting into it.

As for the number of records returned.  Unless you have a JOIN, or a WHERE clause, or a GROUP BY, or a DISTINCT, this should return exactly the same number of records as exists in the source table.

Is this exactly the query you are running?

Comment: Yes, it's exactly the query I am running. I would like to create a new table ModifiedLocation and insert the modified data into it. It's an ETL exercise but I don't have access to SQL Server integration services which is why I am doing it "by hand".